# HUD causes Firefox to lag when its window loses focus

Tags: 13.10, firefox, hud

So, I have 13.10 installed, and Firefox has been slow lately. After opening preferences, whenever I click on another window then click back to Firefox, it takes 5-10 seconds for anything I do to register.  This has been happening both with Firefox 26-28, by the way. (Sticking with the stable branches for now.) None of my add-ons are known to be particularly grievous offenders when it comes to performance. (about:memory categorizes the whole batch of add-ons as taking only 31 MB of memory out of the 1GB that Firefox sometimes requires.) I dual-boot and don't have this performance issue with Firefox in Windows. Is there a way I can diagnose the issue?

[update:] I seem to be able to replicate this issue happening anytime after I open the HUD in any application. Does anyone have a work around besides the obvious "Don't use HUD"?

Comment: @DK Bose: Firefox behaves normally besides that. Have Chrome installed, but have not tested there, but I'm doubtful that it is affected. No other applications I've tested are affected by this.

Comment: I have had similar problems on 12.10 and I think I solved them (finger crossed) by disabling all the unity/ubuntu related extensions: "Ubuntu Firefox Modifications", "Unity Desktop Integration" and "Unity Websites Integration"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by this bug:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/968533

Some workarounds from the thread somewhat in order of drasticness:

- type about:config into the firefox address bar, set setting
  ui.use_unity_menubar = false
- Disable firefox unity plugins
- Install compiz config settings manager and disable the alt HUD entirely
  as described in [How do you disable Alt as the HUD key in 13.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/305108/how-do-you-disable-alt-as-the-hud-key-in-13-04)